# How to access state from a helper module in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm creating a module named **isMember**. This module should be able to check if `state.current_user.member` is true or not.

```
  1 import { select } from "redux-saga/effects"
  2
  3 export function* isMember() {
  4   const { member } = yield select((state: any) => state.current_user)
  5   console.log("isMember: ", member)
  6   return member
  7 }
```

I'm trying to test it like this in my view:

```
import { isMember } from "../utils/isMember"

return (
   { isMember() && <span> is a member </span> }
)
```

But that yields this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`select` is an Effect object of `redux-saga`. It is a tool to handle redux's side effects and should be used exclusively in a saga.

Generally, to test your module, you need to put it in a saga watcher that watches over an action:

```
import { takeEvery } from 'redux-saga'

function* watchTestingAction() {
  yield takeEvery(TESTING_ACTION_TYPE, isMember)
}
```

and dispatch that action in React component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

...
return (
   <MainContainer withScroll>
     <GjeButton
       title="isMember?"
       onPress={this.props.testingAction} />

...
const mapState = (state) => ({})
const mapDispatch = (dispatch) => ({
  testingAction: () => dispatch({ type: TESTING_ACTION_TYPE })
})
export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(YourComponent)
```

EDIT: To get state data, `redux-saga` is not needed. What you need is `connect` from `react-redux`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

...
class MyComponent extends Component
  render() {
    return (
     <MainContainer withScroll>
       <GjeButton
         title="isMember?"
         onPress={() => { console.log(this.props.isMember) }} />
    )
  }
}

const mapState = (state) => ({
  isMember: state.current_user.member || false
})
export default connect(mapState)(YourComponent)
```

Comment: But how can I make a method that returns true or false?

Comment: Thanks! That works, but I would love if I could give `utils/isMember` the responsibility of accessing the state. The consumer of `isMember` should not be bothered with looking into state. :)